# Is “have the steel” an idiom in the statement, “Mitt Romney would have the steel to order the 2011 operation that killed Osama bin Laden in Pakistan”?

Tags: idioms

I found the phrase “*have the steel*” in the following sentence of Time magazine’s article (April 30) titled, “Why Obama Owns bin Laden.”

“Judging from the Republican response, President Obama's ad asking whether Mitt Romney would have ordered the raid that captured Osama bin Laden raises serious questions

There is a kind of biographical line running between those dusty sparring matches a world away and the ad the Obama re-election campaign has released on the question of whether Mitt Romney would *have the steel* to order the 2011 operation that killed Osama bin Laden in Pakistan.”

As I assumed “Mitt Romney would ‘have the steel’ to order the 2011 operation” means “Romney had the guts to order the raid,” I checked English dictionaries online to make it sure:

Cambridge English Dictionary registers “have nerves of steel, meaning ‘to be brave,’ but not “have the steel.”

OED registers “have the nerve to” and “get a nerve doing,” but not “have the steel.”

Merriam-Webster registers neither ‘have the steel’ nor “have nerves of steel.”

Is “have the steel” an idiom or common usage meaning “be brave” or “have the guts” as I guessed? Can I say “He had the steel to tell his boss ‘you’re wrong’?”

Comment: Are you sure that ...'?" is correct? I would have written ...'BLANKSPACE"? (+1 for intersting question, as always)

Comment: @Carlo_R. Can you elaborate  a bit more for me what “...?” is refering to, and what “I would have written ...'BLANKSPACE" means?

Comment: I agree with what others have said - this is not a common idiom so we can only speculate as to what it means.

Comment: A related idiom is _have the stones_, but perhaps the author thought that was too vulgar for _Time_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the context of the article, it seems pretty clear that "*have the steel*" refers to having bravery, fortitude, resolve, and the ability to "not blink under pressure."

I would suggest that the term "*have the steel*" is not yet an established idiom (as your research indicates), but it may be one writer's shorthand for "*have the steely resolve*," as "*steely resolve*" is an idiom that has been has been growing [steadily in popularity over the past 20 - 30 years](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=steely%20resolve&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Perhaps this author thought it was time to shorten that phrase, lest it come across as trite.

To answer your last question, can you jump on board, and say, “He had the *steel* to tell his boss ‘you’re wrong’?” – I think you can.  I can't imagine being confused by that wording.  The word "steel" has been used often enough similar contexts (such as "*nerves of steel*"); I think it's clear what you mean, and the message is unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

I'd never head of someone 'having the steel' so (based on a tiny sample size admittedly) I don't think it's all that common. Again - tiny sample size, grain of salt...

As to what the writer was going for... well, my opinion is the original author was trying to evoke something along the lines of 'would Mitt Rommney have had the willpower and determination to order the operation and see it through?' much like @fumblefingers said.

I don't know if it'd necessarily be usable as "He had the steel to tell his boss ‘you’re wrong’?" as I don't get enough of a sense of making a considered decision and being both aware of the long term work required to enact it.

Just as a fair warning, text below this point is me trying to unpack in my head why I've got this particular translation of 'to have the steel to', and so warnings as to whether or not it makes complete sense should apply.

---

Righto.

I come to this point based on pretty much the same thought process @fumblefingers describes, except my particular experiences with the entire iron vs steel comparison (in both literal and literary senses) don't go with durability in a sense of corrosion and wear, but more in terms of how the two materials resist force, and ultimately, a question of endurance.

Specifically, the distinction is that both are strong but where iron will tend to fail catastrophically and shatter, steel will tend to bend and deform, yet remain *roughly* true to the original piece. So on one hand, something incredibly strong and unchanging, but still where if you could muster enough force, it *might* break, versus something that you almost certainly can deform, but could never truly distort from it's original form, and is thus, ultimately enduring (even if it's going to get a bit beat out of shape).

- This sort of explains (to me) why you get someone with an iron will, and a ruler with an iron fist - both phrasings going for the entire 'unshakeable, unchangeable, unstoppable, unyielding, uncompromising' type of feeling. Probably not related, but an iron maiden also fits into this category.
- On the flipside, you then have someone described as having nerves of steel (someone who in the face of incredible adversity is going to be stressed out, and might waver, but is absolutely never, ever, going to break) or suchlike. One contemporary reference that comes to mind is a tweet from cyclist Robbie McEwen: ["...half of stage simple in comparison.Aussie steel- bends but doesn't break ;)"](https://twitter.com/#!/mcewenrobbie/status/19005147880) in reference to a particularly bad day on the 2010 Tour De France where he spent most of the last half riding alone, up some awful, awful mountains. Normally the sprinters like him would form a group and grind up the mountain together to save energy and well, actually make it to the end. Usually a lone sprinter when faced with something like that would actually just drop out of the race and retire.. McEwen in this case is referring to being particularly bloody minded, and determined to finish the stage hence the entire steel/endurance thing coming out.
- I've also read in more than one place (but can't place it, sorry) where an individual's faith has been likened to steel in a positive sense in that the individual has the capacity to shift and adapt, but is fundamentally enduring. This was contrasted with someone who was overly orthodox in their faith and being likened to iron, funnily enough. One of the unspoken things in the story being the comparison between a 'pure' (read:naive) form of faith, vs a more practical (read:tempered) form of it. Could've been a novel, seems like the kind of thing you'd get as a lesson-teaching type of thing.
- lastly, and this is just purely physical - steel is arguably a more refined form of iron, with precisely controlled amounts of impurities, and as such, is a bit more 'refined' or 'advanced'

So, with all of that bouncing in my head, and going back to the original writer, while I don't *think* it was intentional, you could actually read it quite poetically if you take steel as meaning 'strong, but flexible, and enduring, and a more refined thing':

> ...the question of whether Mitt Romney would have been *strong enough and wise enough to swallow his own personal disgust at ordering a man be killed, knowing full well the kind of criticism it would (possibly rightfully) attract, and whether or not he would be mature enough to calmly weigh the alternatives, make the decision, and see it through without waver from it if he truly believed it was the best thing to* order the 2011 operation that killed Osama bin Laden in Pakistan.

Answer (score 1):

OED gives as one of the figurative senses for *steel* (specifically in the domain of **sport**) - *Power of endurance or sustained effort.* I think the allusion stems from the fact that **steel** lasts longer (corrodes less) than **iron**, which is more often figuratively referenced for its hardness (*iron fist, The Iron Lady*, etc.). Personally, I think it's a somewhat dated expression.

Thus *to **have the steel** [to do something]* doesn't really mean *have the nerve*. It means *have the staying power to see something through that might involve protracted effort*. But in practice, because the expression is quite rare relative to *nerves of steel*, very likely many people will understand them to mean much the same thing.

I have to say it seems quite possible to me the *writer* in OP's case may have conflated the two idioms. It's not obvious that Obama needed a lot of "endurance" to order the raid - it was something which would either succeed or not, in a fairly short timeframe. One might more appropriately ask whether a leader had *the steel to engage militarily in Afghanistan*, since by now I'm sure everyone knows *that's* something that really is expected to take a long time.

Comment: For some reason, when I first read the question, the phrase that popped into my head was "brass balls".  But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @MT_Head: I've not heard that one. Sounds like a conflation of *got the brass* (got the bare-faced cheek) and *got the balls* (got the bottle/nerve/courage).

Comment: @MT_Head: I'm with you on that one. There's actually a great scene in Glengarry Glen Ross involving Alec Baldwin's character, and a close up of him holding a pair of brass balls while berating a room of real estate salesmen. (the balls being, of course, strategically placed for emphasis)

Comment: @tanantish - Another favorite of mine is "You want to see if I've got the minerals?" - which might be a common saying in the UK, but which I've only ever heard in the movie [*Snatch*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0208092/quotes).  Cracks me up, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Since the lines in question apparently refers to the prompt decision to give an order to raid on bin Laden’s hideout (to ultimately kill him!), it appears to me that “have the brass balls (or guts)‘ is closer to the gist of the text, “Romney would have the (same) steel to order the operation’ as Obama had " than “had endurance,” which would requires a long span of efforts, but I’m not sure. By the way, Readers English Japanese Dictionary at hand registers “have cast-iron balls” meaning “be brave, darling.”

Comment: @Yoichi: Yes - as my answer suggests, it's pretty obvious the *Time* writer meant "nerve", irrespective of what OED says the expression "means" in an absolute sense. A couple of people have downvoted my answer, but they haven't said why. It may be they're familiar with the expression used to mean "nerve", but I kinda doubt that - most likely it's just because they can see what the writer means *here*, and are simply disagreeing with me/OED on that basis. btw - *brass balls* is a bit of a "mixed metaphor" - strictly speaking it's either *brass* or *balls*, but not both!

Comment: @MT_Head: I saw *Snatch* for the first time a couple of weeks ago. Great film. Three of us watched it, all with a pretty good ear for "Sarf London villains" slang, and we all thought the dialogue was 100% convincing. Not that I'm familiar with that usage of *minerals* (I suppose it's drifted across from *balls*, aka *stones*). Not that I'd care if it was coined by the scriptwriter - for me, the dialogue & delivery in *Snatch* is right up there with [Sexy Beast](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0203119/) and [44-inch Chest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0914837/). Sharp enough to draw blood!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - re: *Snatch* - my first impression, hearing *minerals*, was "vitamins and minerals" - in the US we have an expression "Wow! You must've eaten your Wheaties this morning!", meaning "your (as advertised) nutritious breakfast has made you surprisingly prepared for the events of the day!"  But the second time the phrase came up in the movie, I made the association with *stones*.  I suspect that such a dual interpretation is exactly what was intended.  I've also appropriated Brick Top's line "I'm sweet enough" whenever I'm offered sugar for my coffee - it always gets a laugh.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I do disagree, however, that "brass balls" is a mixed metaphor.  I believe that the intended implication is that you not only have testicles, but that they are surprisingly large, hard, and heavy - i.e. you do things that are so brave/rash that only someone under the influence of testosterone overdose would even consider them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Though I cannot judge whether ‘brass balls’ is misuse or not as I’m not native speaker(discussion on balls is a rare and amusing argument, isn’t it?), I feel like seconding MT_Head’s interpretation – ‘brass’ simply modifying ‘balls.’ I take ‘brass balls’ as harder, steely, and more ‘resolute’ balls than just the balls (courage) average persons have.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Idiomatically I don't think *brass* has much connection to hard/steely. Military *top brass* aren't "tough" - they just have shiny brass medals and buttons. And if I'm not mistaken, Japan foisted *brass monkeys* on Western Civilisation (though we came up with the expression *cold enough to freeze the balls of a brass monkey). I think the idiomatic *brass = cheek, impudence* comes from brass being resistant to corrosion, rather than actually "hard", like, say, iron.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is, or needs to be, an idiom.

> steel = resolve